# How to make sure that a Java game accepts keyboard-input as soon as it starts?

Tags: java, click

I am using Java to create a graphical game and every time I wish to run it, I need to click the mouse in-game in order for all the movement to be enabled. Nothing works if I try to move without clicking the mouse first. How can I fix this.

Comment: When you say graphical, are you using Swing/AWT or some specific Java Library? It would be nice to add code! Add the part where you initialize your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling requestFocus() on your window

Comment: `requestFocus()` very intuitive, but also deprecated.  See instead `requestFocusInWindow(true)`.  Anything that starts with 'Try' should probably be a comment.